# protractor how to update the value in forloop condition javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, protractor

I have a filter pop-up in the page. I am trying to iterate through the radio buttons in the filter pop-up, for the first time I am able to read the number of radio buttons. After selecting certain radio option then there will be new radio buttons displayed and now the count should be more than previous count. I am trying to read the new counts but not able to assign it to the variable in for loop (totalradios)

```
 var value;
 filterButton.click().then(function () {
  filteroptions.count().then(function (totalradios) {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalradios; i++) {
      (function (index) {
        filteroptions.get(index).click();
        filterSubmit.click();  //page refreshed with new results
        filterButton.click();   //reopened the filter pop-up
        getfiltercount().then(function (value) {

        })
        console.log("recalulated totalradios" + value);
        totalradios = result.filteroptions;
      })(i);
    }
  });
})
```

in a new function I am trying to reverify the radiobuttons and returning it to the call

```
var getfiltercount = function () {
filteroptions = element.all(by.css("md-radio-group.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid._md.layout-row.ng-not-empty md-radio-button")); // filtertext
  return filteroptions.count().then(function (addradios) {
  console.log("addradios is " + addradios);
  })
return addradios;
// done();
}
```

But when I try to print the console I am getting undefined at

```
console.log("recalulated totalradios" + value)
```

All I want it I need to update the value of totalradios with new list of elements in the page

[image: filter pop-up with radio button No selected]

[image: filter pop-up with radio button Yes selected]

Answer (score 0):

### returning the value to resolve the promise

Let's go through and discuss where things are getting not set. When returning the get filter count, the `filteroptions.count` returns a number. You call `then` to console log the amount of `addradios`. Your return type of this method is void. So the result of the following is a promise for type void.

```
return filteroptions.count().then(function (addradios) {
  console.log("addradios is " + addradios);
}
```

Other problems, we have a scoped variable for `addradios` and you are returning it at the end. I don't think this will work. So how can we rewrite this?

```
let filterOptions = element.all(by.css("md-radio-group.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid._md.layout-row.ng-not-empty md-radio-button")); // filtertext
getFilterCount = () => {
  return filterOptions.count().then(count => {
    console.log("number of addradios: " + count);
    return count;
  });
}
```

### Loop through an element.all

I did not use the getFilterCount in the snippet blow. Next looping through an element.all:

```
filterButton.click().then(() => {
  // assuming that options is constant even after a page refresh
  return filterOptions.forEach(filterOption => {
    return filterOption.click().then(() => {
      return filterSubmit.click().then(() => {
        return filterButton.click();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @cnishina. images attached for your reference.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, the radios change from page to page (looking at 5 then at 9). I'm not sure the above loop will work at all. Maybe find better ways to identify the radio?